# Initializers not called in development environment when class changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, development-environment

I have a an initializer in my Rails 3.2 app that includes modules at startup based on a configuration file.  It looks something like this:

```
Array(Settings.site.authentications).map(&:to_sym).each do |sym|
  AuthAuth.class_eval do
    include Object.const_get(sym)
  end
end

Array(Settings.site.authorizations).map(&:to_sym).each do |sym|
  AuthAuth.class_eval do
    include Object.const_get(sym)
  end
end

# This exception is never raised when I start the server.  So the includes 
# appear to be working correctly.
raise "method not found!" unless AuthAuth.new.respond_to? :dynamically_included_method
```

`AuthAuth` is used in my `ApplicationController` in a `:before_filter` to ensure that users are authenticated and authorized.  It works fine and suites the requirement that I have a configurable way of setting authorization and authentication logic on a per-site basis.

I've noticed, however, that when I am running the server in development mode if I make a code change to any class in the application, `AuthAuth` reverts to it's default behavior without the included modules.

Is there an appropriate place to include this code other than an initialization file?

This is a relatively minor issue.  It's easy enough to restart the development server after each code change, but I'm curious.